# Correct usage of \ifmmode

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, align

Seems that there is some subtlety in using `\ifmmode` that I am not aware of.  For some reason, using:

```
\newcommand{\hlcodeA}[1]{\ifmmode\else\small\fi\texttt{\hilight{#1}}}%
```

is not quite identical to:

```
\newcommand{\hlcodeB}[1]{\texttt{\hilight{\ifmmode\else\small\fi#1}}}%
```

where I moved the `\ifmmode` test to the inner level of the macro from the outer.

Both are ok, **except** in an `align`environment where `\hlcodeB` has no problems, but `\hlcodeA` yields a warning:

> LaTeX Font Warning: Command \small invalid in math mode on input line 26

### Notes:

- No problems are reported when used in an `equation` environment.
- The MWE below yields a warning, but replacing `\hlcodeA{y2}` with `\hlcodeB{y2}` in the `align` environment, no warnings are reported.
- This example is not really intended to produce proper output in math mode, but it seems that I am *abusing* the `align` environment in my real example.  This is old code for my internal documentation where I now know that I should have used `tabular` instead -- this was not obvious to me in early 2011 when I started this document :-) , and am just now trying to clean up some of the warnings.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\hilight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}%


\newcommand{\hlcodeA}[1]{%
    \ifmmode\else\small\fi\texttt{\hilight{#1}}%
}%

\newcommand{\hlcodeB}[1]{%
    \texttt{\hilight{\ifmmode\else\small\fi#1}}%
}%


\begin{document}
\hspace*{5.0cm}\hlcodeA{y} = \hlcodeA{x}%   This is ok (no warnings)

\begin{equation*}%         This is ok (no warnings)
\hlcodeA{y1} = \hlcodeA{x1}
\end{equation*}

\begin{align*}%         This is NOT ok (warnings but only from \hlcodeA)
\hlcodeA{y2} = \hlcodeB{x2}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

At the start of an alignment cell TeX expands macros looking for `\omit` (`\multicolumn`) the math start in the cell template has not been added at this point so `\ifmmode` is always false.

You need to put `\relax` in front of it to kill the pre-scan for `\omit` or make the command containing this construct be robust so it doesn't expand in this context (using LaTeX `\DeclareRobustCommand` or eTeX `\protected`)

---

To show the various approaches, this plain eTeX file

```
\def\foo{\ifmmode \phi\else fi\fi}
\protected\def\pfoo{\ifmmode \phi\else fi\fi}
\def\rfoo{\relax\ifmmode \phi\else fi\fi}

\halign{#)&$#$\hfill&\quad dif#cult\cr
0&\omit $\phi$\hfill&\omit \quad dif{f}icult\cr
1&\omit $\phi$\hfill&\omit \quad difficult\cr
2&\foo&\foo\cr
3&\pfoo&\pfoo\cr
4&\rfoo&\rfoo\cr
}


\bye
```

produces

[image]

(0) loses the ffi ligature.

(1) is what you want.

(2) the non robust unprotected command gets the ffi ligature but messes up the if math test.

(3) the etex `\protected` macro does the same as (1).

(4) using `\relax` (which would be the same as using `\DeclareRobustCommand` in LaTeX in this context) gets the math test correct but loses the ffi ligature.

Comment: Yep, using `\newcommand{\hlcodeA}[1]{\relax\ifmmode\else\small\fi\texttt{\hilight{#1}}}` yields no errors. So it seems I would have had this problem even with tabular.  Hmmm, it appears I can't quite accept this answer yet -- probably need to get more rep to accept answers quicker.

Comment: But then under what conditions should I _not_ use `\relax\immode`? Clearly there must be such a case, otherwise it would have been built into `\ifmmode`?

Comment: when `\relax` would be a bad idea.

Comment: :-)  Ok, so when could `\relax` be a bad idea before a `\immode`?  If it is complicated, I can post another question?

Comment: in particular if the command _isn't_ in math mode the `\relax` can have some unwanted affects such as stopping ligatures. Also of course sometimes you need the command to work by expansion only so it _can_ come before `\omit` and `\relax` stops that.