# Declare command for both math and text mode: Spacing

Tags: math-mode, spacing, text-mode

I want to create a command `\points` working in both math and text mode. Unfortunately I still have problems creating the correct (horizontal) spacing after several attempts. Here is my basic „setup“, where I am missing space *before* `\points{3}` inside math mode.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand \points { m } {\text{[#1\,P]}}

\begin{document}

Sentence end \points{1}. Between \points{2} words.

$x^2 + 9 = 0 \points{3}$

\end{document}
```

## Result

[image: Example]

Comment: I think that you forgot the most basic tag: `macro`...

Comment: I’m not sure why you need the command in math mode to begin with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Math mode eats up spaces, so you have to enforce one.

You can change the macro to:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \points { m } {\ifmmode\ \fi\text{[#1\,P]}}
```

or enforce the space when using the command:

```
$x^2 + 9 = 0\ \points{3}$
```

but not both, otherwise you'll get two spaces.

Also, notice that I replaced, following @egreg's remark, `\DeclareDocumentCommand` by `\NewDocumentCommand`.

`\DeclareDocumentCommand` has a behavior akin to `\def` regarding already defined commands. It will create the command no matter what, so you may be replacing an already existing macro with this.

`\NewDocumentCommand`, on the other hand, is equivalent to LaTeX's `\newcommand`; it will check if the command being created already exists and, if it does, an error will appear.

Comment: You should add a `\relax` prior to `\ifmmode`, see for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82653/correct-usage-of-ifmmode).

Comment: @Skillmon Not with a command defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` that also, by the way, is preferable to `\DeclareDocumentCommand`.

Comment: @egreg Can you point to a reference that explains why, please?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik because a command created with `\NewDocumentCommand` or `\DeclareDocumentCommand` is `\protected` (which happens to be one of the working examples in David Carlisle's answer I linked to). I just forgot about that, my bad. Reference is the [`xparse` documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse), section 0.7 (in the current version).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The `\relax` is needed for standard macros starting with `\ifmmode`, because math mode does not start in `array` cells until after TeX has checked for `\omit` (in LaTeX lingo, `\multicolumn`). For macros defined with `\NewDocumentCommand`, `\RenewDocumentCommand` and also `\DeclareRobustCommand` this is not needed, because they are already protected against this.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\points[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrel{[#1\,\mathrm{P}]}}}    
\begin{document}    
    Sentence end \points{1}. Between \points{2} words.

    $x^2 + 9 = 0 \points{3}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you add `\ifmmode\text{\space}` to the command, it will always insert a space in front if used in math mode. Also, I used `\newcommand` instead of `\NewDocumentCommand` since making a command that takes a single mandatory argument does not require the more advanced functionality of `\NewDocumentCommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\points[1]{\relax\ifmmode\text{ }\fi\text{[#1\,P]}}

\begin{document}

Sentence end \points{1}. Between \points{2} words.

$x^2 + 9 = 0 \points{3}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should add a `\relax` prior to `\ifmmode`, see for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82653/correct-usage-of-ifmmode).

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks I've never thought of adding a defensive `\relax` before. Seems like good practice whenever you don't have control over what comes before your conditional.

Comment: except when it isn't:-)