# Missing } inserted and wrong conditional branch in align*

Tags: math-mode, errors, align

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\eta_i\in{}&\ifmmode\mathcal C^\infty\else$\mathcal C^\infty$\fi
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Typing pdflatex in the command line and running this, I would expect it to work. `align*` is a math mode environment, so the `\ifmmode` should take the YES branch, and just produce `\mathcal C^\infty`. However, that is not the case. The result of the above is `Missing } inserted`, and if I add `\show\mathcal` right after the `\else`, the `\show` gets executed, meaning it's going into the NO branch as if it weren't in math mode. If I remove the `&`, however, everything works fine, and the result is:

[image]

Same goes with `xelatex`.

What is going on here? Why is it not in math mode after the `&`?

Comment: What's the purpose of `\ifmmode` inside `align*`?

Comment: Try adding a `\relax` before `\ifmmode`, explanation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82656/3929 (founf via a simple google search on `latex ifmmode align`

Comment: @egreg This is just an MWE. The `\ifmmode` part is from a macro `\Cinf` that's supposed to ensure math mode. This way, when I have to say a function is smooth, I can just type `\Cinf` without dollars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `align` environment is defined in terms of the primitive function `\halign`.

When TeX is processing `\halign` and finds `&` it ignores following explicit spaces and expands tokens in order to see whether `\omit` or `\span` follows. Only after finding either of them or neither, it inserts the template for the current column.

The template for an even numbered column in `align` is basically

```
$\displaystyle#$\hfill
```

where `#` stands for the cell content, found by scanning to the next `&` or row ending.

What happens in your case is that `\ifmmode` is expanded and TeX is ***not*** in math mode at the time, so what remains is `$\mathcal C^\infty$`

Now TeX applies the template, resulting in

```
$\displaystyle$\mathcal C^\infty$$
```

which places `\mathcal` outside of math mode. Hence the error.

A naïvely defined macro

```
\newcommand{\Cinfty}{\ifmmode\mathcal{C}^\infty\else$\mathcal{C}^\infty$\fi}
```

would not solve the issue. The LaTeX kernel provides `\ensuremath` for the purpose:

```
\newcommand{\Cinfty}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{C}^\infty}}
```

But you should think twice (or more) before doing this as you have no advantage whatsoever in being able to type `\Cinfty` in text mode instead of the correctly marked up `$\Cinfty$`. Note that `$\Cinfty$` and `\Cinfty{}` require the same number of keys.

Comment: A `\Cinf` like that is where I came from. I actually also noticed that putting a `\relax` after the `&` fixed the problem. I may have defined it at a time when I didn't know about `\ensuremath`. `\Cinf\ ` saves one keystroke, and two shifts, not to mention that if I have `\Cinf.` `\Cinf,` `\Cinf;` `\Cinf:` I have saved two characters both with a shift, so I guess when I had to take notes it felt like a valid reason for such a macro. And now I'm used to it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can't use the `\ifmmode` inside `math`, and this command is used to define something, the modified `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\calC}{\relax\ifmmode\mathcal{C}^{\infty}\else%
$\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$\fi}%


\begin{align*}
\eta_i\in{}&\calC
\end{align*}

\calC

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks to `daleif` comment above...